# Why disable ssh for root user

Tags: ssh, security

Lot of articles recommend deactivating ssh for root user with `PermitRootLogin no` in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`. There is also a lot of questions on serverfault about *implementing* root ssh deactivation.

But what is motivation for that?

It makes the attacker to guess the user name in addition. But shouldn't the cryptographic strength of public-private keys and RSA encryption be enough?

I am asking not just out of curiosity, but because using non-root user [requires additional trade-offs in ansible usage](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/become.html#becoming-an-unprivileged-user): `pipelining` (compatibility) or `allow_world_readable_tmpfiles`(security).

Comment: your ansible statement is false

Comment: @JacobEvans I'll prepare minimal example, which describes my context ans post as separate question

Comment: !requiretty for you sudo policy probably solves your second question

Comment: @TimBrigham Yes, is duplicate, thanks! I searched, but did not find this other question since question title does not contain `ssh`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. every system has a root user,  making it 1 step easier up brute force your system.
2. audit trails are impossible without named accounts
3. ansible uses ssh/winrm/apis (like nxos) all using standards and all supporting named accounts,  kerberos, public key and password authentication.

Answer (score 1):

The root account is prize target for attackers as it is root and it is a default/predictable account to target for brute force attacks. If an attacker needs to brute force the username as well as the password the attack will take a lot longer to be successful and when it is successful it will not be against the root account, so the impact *may* be limited.